# What is the equivalent LINQ to SQL query expression of this SQL statement?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, t-sql

SQL query run OK:

```
select o.OpName,isnull(Amount,0) from Setup_tblOperator o
 left join 
 (
    select t.opid,sum(isnull(t.Amount,0)) Amount from  
    Load_tblTransaction t  
    where  cast(t.RequestTime as date)='2017-04-24'
    group by t.opid
 ) t on t.OpId=o.OpId 
 where o.IsActive=1
```

I tried following code in LINQ to SQL:

```
var trans = (from o in mouDataEntities.Setup_tblOperator
             join t in mouDataEntities.Load_tblTransaction 
             on o.OpId equals t.OpId into ot
             from n in ot.Where(
                     t => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.RequestTime) == 
                     DbFunctions.TruncateTime(seldate))
                 .DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 Operator = o.OpName,
                 Amount=  n.Amount
             });           

var gt = trans.GroupBy(t => t.Operator)
    .Select(n => new { Operator = n.Key, Amount = n.Sum(a=>a.Amount) })
    .ToList();
```

It throws an error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized
>   value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query
>   must use a nullable type.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory.  You have a DB value that is nullable and you are trying to cast it to and `int` which is not nullable.

Comment: Thank you Yannick Meeus. I was expecting someone edit/format my question.

Comment: There are some cases where it's not a straightforward DB nullable field, this can happen for non-nullable fields when the returned collection is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few cases where the straightforward SQL to C# translation gets accepted, but fails at run-time. In C#, `set.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(n => n.Amount)`, where `n.Amount` has type `int`, would have a result type `IEnumerable<int>`. It would fail with a `NullReferenceException` if `set` were empty, because in that case `n` would become `null` as well. Therefore, there is no reason why you'd need `int?`, since you can't ever get `null` as a result.

In SQL, it's not so easy. Retrieving a column of the default row introduced by `LEFT JOIN` is valid, and produces `NULL`.

But the C# code is expecting a value of type `int`, and an `int` can't be `null`.

You need to find some way to trick the type system so that you can specify how `null` should be handled. A simple cast suffices:

Change

```
Amount = n.Amount
```

to

```
Amount = (int?) n.Amount
```

Or, to turn `null` into `0`,

```
Amount = (int?) n.Amount ?? 0
```

Comment: thanks for comment. It solved my problem but need some extra code to fix NULL error. I added this code:            var gt = trans.GroupBy(t => t.Operator).Select(n => new { Operator = n.Key, Amount = n.Sum(a=>a.Amount.GetValueOrDefault(0)) }).ToList();

Comment: @Iqbal That's perfectly valid, though my preference in this case would be to get rid of the `null` as early as possible. Edited to include that.

Comment: Sorry to say that I'm a new user can't up vote you. You solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Iqbal You can [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) though